# default export is not declared in imported module

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using ES6 in IntelliJ IDEA. Below is a piece of code.

```
import controller from './tpmInfo.ctrl.js'
import template from './tpmInfo.tpl.html' //default export is not declared in imported module

export default angular.module('tmpApp', [])
    .component('tpmInfo', {
        template: template,
        controller: controller,
        bindings: {
            ags: '='
        }
    })
.name;
```

The `template` html is a normal html, but IntelliJ IDEA throws warning "default export is not declared in imported module". Is there any way to make this warning disappear? Thanks.

Comment: It probably expects `./tpmInfo.tpl.html` to resolve to an ES6 module, not some arbitrary other resource provided by your loader.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
import * as tpl from './tpmInfo.tpl.html'
```

and then use it like this:

```
template: tpl.template,
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: BTW, what module loader or bundlers are you using? SystemJs? Webpack?

Comment: We are using Webpack.

Comment: Hi, can you revert your answer to the previous version? My code is in `app.js` so I don't have to set up Webpack here. Your previous answer works for me. Thanks! So the solution is: `import * as template from './app.tpl.html'` and `template: template`.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular2-Meteor projects I had to do like Wassim says, with small changes:

`import * as tpl from './tpmInfo.tpl.html'`
and then in Component
`template: tpl.default`

or

```
import * as templatefrom './tpmInfo.tpl.html';  
template = template.default;

  @Component({
   //smth,      
    template
  })
```

this is a string, returned by `angular2-compilers` module